# Need help combining 2 queries into 1

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please tell me why I keep getting an error right before the where clause in this query? It works fine if I don't have any where clause.

```
SELECT  
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT threadid) FROM thread) AS threads,  
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT postid) FROM post) AS posts  
WHERE
  post.dateline >= 1299905258 AND
  thread.dateline >= 1299905258
```

Both table have the dateline field. Is it a syntax issue or am I trying to accomplish something that can't be done this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the `FROM` clause?

Basically when you dont have a WHERE clause it is just getting 2 columns for you. When you define a where clause that means you are filtering results from some table .. so now you need the `FROM`

You can try this

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT threadid) FROM thread WHERE dateline >= 1299905258) AS threads,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT postid) FROM post WHERE dateline >= 1299905258) AS posts
```

Comment: Ah okay. I was thinking the FROM thread and FROM post would pull those out. I was reading it all wrong. I did try it somewhat like you have it earlier but I had the WHERE clauses in the wrong position. It makes much more sense now. Thank you. It works fine now.

Is it better to do it this way for speed or would 2 separate queries actually be faster?